# NSPredicate String to get n'th item in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I cannot find a way to get the *n*th item in an array using an `NSPredicate` string. For example:

```
//You cannot touch or modify the code inside this method. You can only use the predicate string param to filter the array.
- (NSArray *)filterUsingNSPredicate:(NSString *)PredicateString 
{
    NSArray *array = @[
        @"firstItem",
        @"secondItem",
        @"thirdItem",
        @"fourthItem",
    ];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:PredicateString];
    NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    NSLog(@"This is the second item in the array! %@",filtered); //Thats the only thing in the array.
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a predicate string and not just `array[indexYouWant]` or `[array objectAtIndex:indexYouWant]`?

Comment: Yes for what im doing, i dont have a reference to the array itself, i can just query using NSPredicateString. I just get the filtered array returned to me in this case.

Comment: you can store that  array in temporary array and use `objectAtIndex` to get n'th element

Comment: Can you explain how you're accessing the array if you don't have a reference to it?

Comment: [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] in this line, what is `array` ?

Comment: if you get array then you can make reference. for example when we call webservice and got json object then we store it in array or dictionary like this way he can take temporary array.

Comment: array is the array declared at the very top @Lion . So im hitting api that filters using NSPredicate, so i dont have the ability to directly index into the array and return it since that would involve me changing the code im hitting. I just have the ability to query using NSPredicate strings.

Comment: can you post your object or list from which you want to get filter array?

Comment: its at the very top!

NSArray *array = @[
    @"firstItem",
    @"secondItem",
    @"thirdItem",
    @"fourthItem",
];

Comment: then you can use `objectAtIndex`. like `[array objectAtIndex : 2]`

Comment: I cant do that. So pretend for a second that the code i pasted in my post is something you cant touch. You cant modify any of it. All you can do is pass in the variable NSString * PredicateStringToGet2ndItemHere as a parameter. Using this, how can you filter the array to return a particular index, for my example, its index 2 (item number 3 in the array).

Comment: It is impossible. if you can filter using predicate then you can do this operation as well. post more code or data which haven't reference. i want to watch it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an item, you don't receive an NSArray, because you will only receive an object.

You can use NSPredicate to search by name of an object in your array. But what you say, that is not what you want.

You can use `[array objectAtIndex:index];`, that returns the object in the position you indicate in index.

If you want the index of an object, you can use `[array indexOfObject:object];`, that returns the index of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create predicate with block https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPredicate/predicateWithBlock%3A like this to get 6-th element (at index 5 counting from 0):

```
__block NSInteger index = 0;
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *bindings)(
    return index++ == 5;
)];
```